# Потокобезопасен ли zap.Logger в Golang?

Tags: golang, логирование

Потокобезопасен ли zap.Logger в Golang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересный вопрос. Нашёл [ишью на ГитХабе по этой теме](https://github.com/uber-go/zap/issues/99), там есть такой пример кода:

```
package main

import "github.com/uber-go/zap"

var logger zap.Logger

func main() {
    logger = zap.NewJSON()

    for i := 0; i < 800; i++ {
        go printer(i)
    }
}

func printer(i int) {
    logger.Info("Counting",
        zap.Int("i", i),
    )
}
```

Который даёт (давал) вывод такого вида:

```
{"msg":"Counting","level":"info","ts":1469196244924860064,"fields":{"i":8}}
{"msg":"Counting","level":"info","ts":1469196244924867134,"fields":{"i":42}}
{"msg":"Counting","level":"info","ts":1469196244924866589,"fields":{"i":20}}
{"msg":"Counti{"msg":"Counting","level":"info","ts":1469196244924879429,"fields":{"i":21}}
ng","level":"info","ts":1469196244924870959,"fields":{"i":9}}
{"msg":"Counting","level":"info","ts":1469196244924879050,"fields":{"i":36}}
{"msg":"Counting","level":"info","ts":1469196244924873937,"fields":{"i":43}}
{"msg":"Counting","level":"info","ts":1469196244924904543,"fields":{"i":22}}
{"msg":"Counting","level":"info","ts":1469196244924910632,"fields":{"i":10}}
{"msg":"Counting","level":"info","ts":1469196244924916792,"fields":{"i":23}}
...
```

На 4-й строке видно наложение. Но [видимо проблему порешали](https://github.com/uber-go/zap/pull/106) примерно в то же время. И обновлённая версия этого примера на всех запусках он выдаёт ровные столбики вывода:

```
package main

import "go.uber.org/zap"

var logger *zap.Logger

func main() {
    logger, _ = zap.NewProduction()

    for i := 0; i < 800; i++ {
        go printer(i)
    }
}

func printer(i int) {
    logger.Info("Counting",
        zap.Int("i", i),
    )
}
```